# Updating the scope variable across multiple controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two controllers- searchBoxController and productList. What I am trying to do is to update the scope variable $scope.products from multiple controllers. I know that defining it as a root variable is a very bad design- but putting that in shared service is not solving the problem. The update doesn't reflect in the HTML templates!

```
function SearchTermService(){
    this.productSearch = function(data, $http){
        var url = "";
        $http.get(url).then(function(resp){
            return resp.data;
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
};

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.service("myService", MyService);
app.service("searchTermService", SearchTermService);
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.products = new Date();
});

app.controller('productList', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, myService) {
    $rootScope.products = prod_res;
});



app.controller('searchBoxController', function($scope, $http, searchTermService, $rootScope){
        $scope.getSearchResults = function(){
        $rootScope.products = searchTermService.productSearch($scope.term, $http)
    };
});
```

PS: I am not sure if I need to have a promise returned while assigning the $rootScope.products in 'searchBoxController', as the console.log says its undefined. Currently I am not returning a promise from the service.

Comment: this code doesn't appear to be using a shared service, rather it appears to be using `$rootScope`.

Comment: Show your `SearchTermService` full code.

Comment: I had put the shared service code- ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers. But since it was not working- I got back to using to $rootScope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to update a scope variable across multiple controller, you can use **angular service**.

You should use this because **all** angular services are **singletons**, so you can easily share common logic, share data between controller.

I've made an example where I use service in order to update some data. Then, my factory return an **object data**, so we will get an **object**, not just a **fixed value**. Thanks to this, our data will be updated, we will keep the binding data.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $timeout, Service) {

  //Retrieve current data object of our service
  $scope.data = Service.value;

  //will be set to 4
  $timeout(function(){
    Service.set(4, 'product');
  }, 1000);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();


(function(){

function Controller2($scope, $timeout, Service) {

  //Retrieve current data object of our service
  $scope.data2 = Service.value;

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller2);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service() {

    //Our data object
    var data = {
      product: null
    };

    function set(value, field){
      data[field] = value;
    }

    return {
      set: set,
      value: data
    };


  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app'>

    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
      <h2>Service value : {{data.product}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>
      <h2>Service value from controller2 : {{data2.product}}</h2>
    </div>

  </body>
```

So, we will **share** our data across multiple controller. By using services, you can avoid to use the `$rootScope`.

You can see the [**Working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UbiEt49oAvIlnm8qo8Tz?p=preview)

Comment: Well thanks Paul for the answer- really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes it works! And you don't even needs events or watchers! Awesome.